# Flutter Doctor - Cannot determine if IntelliJ is installed

Tags: flutter, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, flutter-doctor

> Flutter Doctor - Cannot determine if IntelliJ is installed

I have tried installing flutter 2.2 on my Mac OSX but flutter doctor was throwing a error for IntelliJ. I have already installed IntelliJ IDEA CE on my MAC OSX.

I have followed the below documentation but there was no log which confirms the folder in which it is searching for IntelliJ.
[Reference Manual](https://qnttran.medium.com/flutter-in-multiple-ide-android-intellij-vscode-for-macos-ba928d58b4a4)

```
(base) Thomass-MacBook-Pro:JLPT thomasvimaleasok$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.0, on macOS 11.1 20C69 darwin-x64, locale
    en-IN)
    • Flutter version 2.2.0 at
      /Users/thomasvimaleasok/Projects/flutterapps/flutter
    • Framework revision b22742018b (4 days ago), 2021-05-14 19:12:57 -0700
    • Engine revision a9d88a4d18
    • Dart version 2.13.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/thomasvimaleasok/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✗] Cannot determine if IntelliJ is installed
    ✗ Directory listing failed

[✓] VS Code (version 1.54.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 90.0.4430.212

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: Are you going to use IntelliJ? On https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/54867 (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/54867#issuecomment-658296530) it says, that this error in `flutter doctor` should not have an effect.

Comment: Yes @R_User. If I open the flutter directory in intelij its working perfectly fine. But the flutter doctor is still reporting the error. Thanks for sharing the url but looks like flutter doctor -v is not showing the folder in which we have to make a soft link(ln -s).

Answer (score 0):

I fought with this error for a while, but finally found a solution for my case.

There was a folder in my Applications folder (unrelated to IntelliJ) that wasn't readable. A `sudo chmod a+rx` on that location resolved the problem.

`flutter doctor -vv` turned up the error, but the problem appeared at the beginning of the execution log, and not anywhere near the `Cannot determine if IntelliJ is installed` error.